# How can I group by the output according to label in python

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I am trying to get group by label  of my below result:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5)
kmeans.fit(X)

centroid = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.labels_

print (centroid)
print(labels)

for i in range(len(X)):
   print ("coordinate:" , X[i], "label:", labels[i])
```

Which is giving me the below result:

```
coordinate: [30.5 16.7] label: 2
coordinate: [31.3 21.8] label: 3
coordinate: [34.  17.9] label: 3
coordinate: [33.2 13.8] label: 2
coordinate: [35.9 18.9] label: 3
coordinate: [38.2 19.7] label: 0
coordinate: [36.6 19.8] label: 3
coordinate: [37.3 18.6] label: 0
coordinate: [33.8 21.5] label: 3
coordinate: [34.4 21.2] label: 3
coordinate: [32.1 18.9] label: 3
coordinate: [36.9 22.1] label: 3
coordinate: [31.  24.3] label: 3
coordinate: [32.6 21.8] label: 3
coordinate: [33.2 20.7] label: 3
coordinate: [35.5  0. ] label: 2
coordinate: [47.8 21.4] label: 1
```

How can I get group by label 0,1,2,3,4.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mask](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.generic.html) to get the wanted points.

```py
for class_ in range(5):
    print(f"Class: {class_}:")
    print(X[labels==class_])
```

It will look like:

```
Class: 0:
[[-1.37195659  3.29604478]
 [-1.4811455   2.73069841]
 [-2.41468976  0.93708579]
 [-0.49772229  1.55128226]]
Class: 1:
[[ 7.65935736 -2.5439099 ]
 [ 8.02045985 -1.55367927]
 [ 8.76360303 -2.76924393]
 [ 7.56698502 -0.38039423]]
Class: 2:
[[1.42013331 4.63746165]
 [1.7373078  4.42546234]
 [1.12031365 5.75806083]
 [2.47034915 4.09862906]
 [0.0058752  4.38724103]]
Class: 3:
[[-1.63558259  7.53315727]
 [-1.59616792  7.99180898]
 [-0.01796509  9.03783986]
 [-2.29680874  6.41544208]]
Class: 4:
[[ 2.91970372  0.15549864]
 [ 4.32502215 -0.55670201]
 [ 2.36833522  0.04356792]]
```

Therefore, if you want to group the points, you can do it like

```py
{class_: X[labels==class_] for class_ in range(5)}
```

Here is the complete code I tried

```py
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

# Create random datasets
X, _ = make_blobs(n_samples=20, centers=5, n_features=2,
                  random_state=0)

# Fit the data
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5)
kmeans.fit(X)

# Get the centers and labels from kmeans
centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.labels_

for class_ in range(5):
    print(f"Class: {class_}:")
    print(X[labels==class_])
```